# Updating an attribute to a foreign key

Tags: sql

So I've currently got a database with a table named subject, within this is the name of the subject and the full name of the person responsible.

I've just added a new table with contact information, which has a primary key employee_id, and other attributes including employee_fn and employee_ln.

What I'm essentially trying to achieve, is to update the 'responsible' attribute from being the full name to being a foreign key referencing employee_id where the name corresponds accordingly.

I'm having trouble writing the SQL for this and honestly can't even work out how to do it manually nor with a query.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what i understand is you want to have responsible column as FK of Subject table and point it to the employee_id as FK ..right??

But that's not possible as FK needs to PK in other table. Employee_id will be an integer and will not be able to hold the full name.

Any sample data with expected output will help you out.

However if you have employee_id as a column in subject table then this update will work.

```
update subject s
set responsible = (
select employee_fn||employee_ln as fullname,employee_id
from 
employee 
) e
where e.employee_id = s.employee_id
```

your subject must have employee_id as fk and employee table as employee_id as PK for PK-FK relationship.